# Cakephp custom validation on dépendent fields with other

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I work by croogo 1.3 of cakephp, so I want to make a form. See my screenshot:

[image] [image])

It has two parts:

1. part [use] [name] [password] [e-mail]
2. parity (it's all fields)

I want to check (validate) all the fields if the checkbox 'profossionnel' is checked, else validated just this field [use] [name] [password] [e-mail]

This is my source code that I tested but it does not worked:

```
public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'isUnique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'The username has already been taken.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
            'validAlias' => array(
                'rule' => 'validAlias',
                'message' => 'This field must be alphanumeric',
                'last' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => 'email',
                'message' => 'Please provide a valid email address.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
            'isUnique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'Email address already in use.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', 6),
            'message' => 'Passwords must be at least 6 characters long.',
        ),
        'verify_password' => array(
            'rule' => 'validIdentical',
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
            'validName' => array(
                'rule' => 'validName',
                'message' => 'This field must be alphanumeric',
                'last' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'website' => array(
            'url' => array(
                'rule' => 'url',
                'message' => 'This field must be a valid URL',
                'allowEmpty' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'company_name' => array(
                'rule' => 'validationRule',
                'message' => 'This code has been used too many times.',
                 'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false
        ),
        'address' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
            'validName' => array(
                'rule' => 'validName',
                'message' => 'This field must be alphanumeric',
                'last' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'zip_code' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
            'validName' => array(
                'rule' => 'validName',
                'message' => 'This field must be alphanumeric',
                'last' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'category' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
                'last' => true,
            ),
            'validName' => array(
                'rule' => 'validName',
                'message' => 'This field must be alphanumeric',
                'last' => true,
            ),
        )

    );

public function validationRule($check) {
  $valid = false;

 // debug($check);
 // debug($this->data['User']['role_id']);


  if ($this->data['User']['role_id'] == '4') {
      $valid = true;
  }
    else {
      $valid = false;
  }
  return $valid;
}
```

Comment: What exactzly "did not work"? any errors?

Comment: I have no error message but it's just I am lookin for a script to validate just [user] [name] [password] [email] if the radio box 'profesonnel' is not tick...my code i think it's not what i am needing

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to prevent an element to validate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042745/how-to-prevent-an-element-to-validate)

Comment: thank you you have given me an idea ....I changed by

[link]http://screencast.com/t/WFfGyO10

but still I could not validate always..... I think this the problem in javascript problem because when I change the value of radio box, it's will not update the validator ( du model)... if possible show me how I do this ajax request to update '$this->User->validator()->remove('company_name');'